# Best subset with exactly one success

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

This is an interview question that I was asked, but I totally couldn't figure it out:

Given N items = {a,b,c,d,e...}, each with a probability {$P_a$,$P_b$,$P_c$,$P_d$,$P_e$...} of succeeding.

Given that you can select any subset of items (i.e {b,c,e}), what is the highest probability you could get such that exactly **ONE** of the item in this subset succeed.

Say you select {b,c,e}
the probability is $P_b$*(1-$P_c$)*(1-$P_e$) + Pc*(1-$P_b$)*(1-$P_e$) + $P_e$*(1-$P_b$)*(1-$P_c$)

If there exist any item x with probability 1, it is best to select only that item.

How can we find out the maximum possible probability given that you can choose any subset?

Comment: I think more information is needed. Do the probabilities sum to 1? If so, couldn't I just pretend the probability of selecting all but $a$ is 0 and then take any subset containing $a$ and be done?

Comment: @Gregory no, I don't think any more information is needed beyond confirmation that the items occur independently of one another.  We want a strategy or algorithm such that given these values $p_a,p_b,p_c,\dots$ that we can find the optimal choice of subset.  Given such a collection of values it is clear that such an optimal choice must exist as there are only finitely many values all of which are bounded within $[0,1]$.

Comment: @lulu letting $F(X)$ be the probability that exactly one element of $X$ occurred, with $n=3$ and $p_a=p_b=0.3$ and $p_c=0.4$ we have $F(\{a,b\})=0.3+0.3-2\cdot 0.09=0.42>0.4=F(\{c\})$, so it isn't necessarily just picking the single element set containing the most common element.  If any of the elements occurred with greater than $0.5$ probability, I expect from intuition that the single element set containing whichever the most common of those to be the best choice, but when they are all less I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Gregory that was a fluke that I picked numbers that happened to add to $1$.  In my example $F(\{a,b,c\}) = 0.3\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.6 + 0.7\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.6 + 0.7\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.4 = 0.448$, ironically an even better choice.  Definitely not $1$ and not greater than $1$.  Similarly, if $p_a=p_b=p_c=1$ we have $F(\{a,b,c\})=0$, not greater than $1$.  Read the question more thoroughly... For each element $i$, it either is or is not picked with probability $p_i$.  We want to find a subset which maximizes the probability that *exactly* one of the elements is picked.

Comment: You should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your posts more readable.  For example, `$P_a$` comes out as $P_a$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, they are independent. Choosing one item would not affect the probability of another item. We know that if there exist an item with probability 1, it would be best to select only this item yielding the optimal probability of 1

Comment: Not sure how to do it efficiently, but I think one can create a filter of subsets to which adding another event does not increase the desired probability; they are subsets $E$ for which $\sum_{e \in E} \frac{p_e}{1-p_e} \geq 1$.

Comment: Btw, was this a question that you were supposed to work out at a board/piece of paper, over a period of time at a computer, over lunch...?

Comment: We could go through all subsets, but that would be too slow O(2^N) for most computers.

I was supposed to give a proof for the problem on a whiteboard, the interviewer said something about an optimal approach of selecting all the K largest probability items at the end

Comment: @BrianTung You could introduce a binary variable $x_i$ to indicate whether $i \in E$ and then impose a linear constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i}{1-p_i} x_i \ge 1$.

Comment: @RobPratt: Unless there's something else, that won't be sufficient, because just this criterion alone won't allow you to choose between one event with $p = 1/2$ and two events with $p = 1/3$, but the former succeeds with probability $1/2$ and the latter with probability only $4/9$.

Comment: @Brian Maybe minimize $\sum_i x_i$?

Comment: @RobPratt: As I assert in my answer, I think you can take the partial derivative of the probability of exactly one success with respect to the probability of success of any event, and it's always non-negative; therefore, you should always use the greedy approach.

Comment: OP: If you want the question to be re-opened (and I think it probably ought to be), it would be helpful if you edited some of your observations from the comments into the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The best strategy is, indeed, to construct a subset by starting with the most probable event, and adding events in decreasing order of probability, until a particular sum attains $1$.

For any event $e$, let $p_e$ be the probability of success, and $q_e = 1-p_e$ the probability of failure.  As a convenient abuse of notation, for any subset of events $E$, let $p_E$ be the probability of exactly one success amongst the events in $E$, and let $q_E \not= 1-p_E$ be the probability of exactly no successes amongst the events in $E$.  We then have

$$
p_E = \left( \prod_{e \in E} q_e \right) \left(\sum_{e \in E} \frac{p_e}{q_e} \right)
$$

Then $E$ is maximal, in the sense that it is not advantageous to add another event to $E$, if for any event $e' \not\in E$, we have

$$
p_{E'} \leq p_E
$$

where $E' = E \cup \{e'\}$.  We find

\begin{align}
p_{E'} & = p_E q_{e'} + q_E p_{e'} \\
       & = p_E - p_E p_{e'} + q_E p_{e'}
\end{align}

so therefore $p_{E'} \leq p_E$ whenever

$$
p_E \geq q_E
$$

Note that this condition does not depend on the event $e'$.  Since

$$
q_E = \prod_{e \in E} q_e
$$

the condition is equivalent to

$$
\sum_{e \in E} \frac{p_e}{q_e} \geq 1
$$

I'll continue on with this approach momentarily.

---

OK, I've had dinner.  Still digesting, so maybe this is hasty, but I think one can justify the greedy approach (taking the largest probability events first) by observing that

$$
\frac{\partial p_E}{\partial p_e} = \frac{1}{(1-p_e)^2} \prod_{e' \in E \not= e} q_{e'} \geq 0
$$

so as long as you keep the number of events the same, you always get a better result by swapping a lower-probability event for a higher-probability event.  However, you may get to a point where you're better off *deleting* an event—and that is precisely when deleting the lowest-probability event leaves the above sum still greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: I think your first displayed equation should instead be $$p_E = \sum_{e \in E} \frac{p_e}{q_e} \prod_{f \in E} q_f$$ or maybe $$p_E = \left(\prod_{e \in E} q_e \right) \sum_{e \in E} \frac{p_e}{q_e}$$ to avoid ambiguity of $e \in E$

Comment: @RobPratt: Yeah, you're probably right.  ETA: Went with the second option (and doubled down on the parentheses).